# Sonar Analysis fails intermittently

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

I am using Sonar server 5.6. When I run the scanner then sometime it fails intermittently for the same piece of code. Its difficult to determine the behaviour. Mostly I saw following two errors.

Error 1

```
    > ===================================================== INFO: 26 source files to be analyzed INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor (done) | time=229ms
    > INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor INFO: 26/26 source files have been
    > analyzed INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=179ms INFO:
    > Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done)
    > | time=521ms INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer INFO:
    > DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for cs INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is
    > used for css INFO: JavaCpdBlockIndexer is used for java INFO:
    > DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for js INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is
    > used for scss INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for ts INFO:
    > DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for web INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is
    > used for xml INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=315ms INFO:
    > Calculating CPD for 187 files INFO: CPD calculation finished INFO:
    > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO:
    > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: Total time: 2:01.227s INFO: Final Memory: 68M/1098M INFO:
    > ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ********************************************

Error 2

    > INFO: Sensor JaCoCoItSensor (done) | time=0ms INFO: Sensor
    > JaCoCoOverallSensor INFO: Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor (done) | time=0ms
    > INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor INFO: 31 source files to be analyzed INFO:
    > Sensor XmlFileSensor (done) | time=641ms INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage
    > Sensor INFO: 31/31 source files have been analyzed INFO: Sensor Zero
    > Coverage Sensor (done) | time=203ms INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
    > INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=266ms INFO: Sensor
    > CPD Block Indexer INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for cs INFO:
    > DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for css INFO: JavaCpdBlockIndexer is
    > used for java INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for js INFO:
    > DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for scss INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer
    > is used for ts INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for web INFO:
    > DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for xml INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
    > (done) | time=250ms INFO: Calculating CPD for 284 files INFO: CPD
    > calculation finished INFO: Analysis report generated in 10578ms, dir
    > size=2 MB INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 1438ms, zip size=1 MB
    > INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 109ms INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you
    > can browse
    > http://<Myserver>/sonar/dashboard/index/my:myproject INFO:
    > Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the
    > server has processed the submitted analysis report INFO: More about
    > the report processing at
    > http://<Myserver>/sonar/api/ce/task?id=12323213
    > INFO: Executing post-job
    > org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker INFO:
    > Executing post-job org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.QualityGateBreaker

INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 7:10.898s
INFO: Final Memory: 74M/1194M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------


    > **************************************
```

I am using SonarQube build breaker plugin as well. one of the reason is it fails waiting for the analysis. I am not getting why it takes more time to process/generate the report. Although most the time it processes the results pretty quickly but sometime it takes too much time. What could be the reason for it?

Can anybody please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Atul

Comment: What is the scanner you are using? Maven (`mvn sonar:sonar`)? SonarQube Scanner (`sonar-scanner`)? Would be interesting to add `-e` to get a detailed error message.

Comment: I am using Sonar-scanner, Thanks, would add the suggested parameter -e.

Comment: Please remove the build breaker plugin. This is not something we recommend to use.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to have gated check-in with Sonar. How can do it without using build breaker plugin?

Comment: Is it working without the build breaker plugin? You would better look for an answer to (or open create a new one for) "how to fail the build when quality gate is ko".

Comment: There are two issues mentioned in the initial question. It seems like sometime Sonar take more time than normal to process the results. This is intermittent behaviour.